# Find XPath Paragraph (following-sibling?)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm using `Selenium` with `Python 2.7.10` and would like to grab the paragraph following the `"Description"` header on this page: http://etfdb.com/etf/ROBO/

```
from selenium import webdriver as driver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def scrape(driver, key):
    try:
        find_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='panel__sub-heading' and . = '%s']/following-sibling::p" % key).text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print "Not Found"
        return None
    else:
        value = re.search(r"(.+)", find_value).group().encode("utf-8")
        print value
        return value

description = scrape(driver, "Description")
```

The XPath I'm using is incorrect because it yields no result. What would be the correct way to find the paragraph following the header `"Description"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `span` tag - it's `h3`:

```
//h3[@class='panel__sub-heading' and . = '%s']/following-sibling::p
```

Comment: Ah, so it was simply that. Thank you :)